# Master-Detail relation to ContentVersion object

Tags: master-detail, contentversion

I'm currently considering the implementation of a solution and I would like to ask for your advice.

The initial requirement is to establish a one-to-many relationship with the **ContentVersion** object (where a **ContentVersion** record can have multiple **ScanResult** records), which is not directly supported in Salesforce. To overcome this limitation, I've devised a solution that involves creating a custom "**proxy**" object. The **Proxy** object will serve as a representation of the **ContentVersion** object and will be connected to it through a reversed lookup relationship. In this setup, the parent would be the **Proxy** object and the child would be **ContentVersion**. Additionally, the proxy object would have a master-detail relationship, fulfilling the initial requirement (each **Proxy** record can have multiple **ScanResults** records).

One drawback of this approach is that it would allow different content versions to be associated with the same proxy, although this can be restricted through code.

I would greatly appreciate any thoughts or suggestions regarding this solution. Thank you in advance.